# Map MouseLeftButtonUp doesn't fire always

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

I'm using BingMaps to make an app that allows to draw shapes over a map. In this code I need to listen for MouseLeftButtonUp and MouseLeftButtonDown in order to understand when the person starts and stops drawing. But for some odd reason the MouseLeftButtonUp doesn't fire always. In this app users can draw freely or shapes, when we draw freely the handler is called but when it is a shape (eg. rectangle) it doesn't get called always. I've searched already and the solution presented for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56228560/leftmouseup-not-firing-bing-maps-mappolyline) doesn't seem to work for me. Also tried using tunneling events but didn't work either.

Here's my Map.xaml:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Satellite_Vessel_Tracker.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Satellite_Vessel_Tracker"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Satellite Vessel Tracker" Height="550" Width="940" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" MinWidth="940" MinHeight="550" MaxHeight="550" MaxWidth="940">
    <m:Map Name="MainMap" CredentialsProvider="..." MouseMove="MainMap_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonDown="MainMap_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="MainMap_MouseLeftButtonUp" Margin="0,0,408.6,-0.4" Height="490"/>

</Window>
```

And here is the code for drawing lines over the map:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;

namespace Line
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private readonly int StrokeThickness = 2;
        private UIElement last;
        Point start, end;

        private void MainMap_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                last = null;
                start = e.GetPosition(MainMap);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void MainMap_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MouseButtonUp");
            end = e.GetPosition(MainMap);
            UIElement shape = DrawLine();
            MainMap.Children.Add(shape);
            last = null;
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void MainMap_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                MainMap.Children.Remove(last);
                end = e.GetPosition(MainMap);
                last = DrawLine();
                MainMap.Children.Add(last);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private UIElement DrawLine()
        {
            MapPolyline line = new MapPolyline()
            {
                Locations = new LocationCollection()
                {
                    MainMap.ViewportPointToLocation(start),
                    MainMap.ViewportPointToLocation(end)
                },
                Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                StrokeThickness = StrokeThickness
            };
            return line;
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

- As stated in one of the comments I've tried using the `AddHandler` method with the `handledEventsToo` flag although it still doesn't get fired all the times.
- Also this happens even when the mouse is within the bounds of the map, as tested with `MouseLeave`.
- `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` doesn't get fired everytime either.

Comment: You can try to subscribe to the event in your code-behind. First rmove the XAML event handler assignment. Then in your MainWindow.xaml.cs file add  the following line to the constructor: `AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(MainMap_MouseLeftButtonUp), true);`. This way you can handle routed events that are marked as handled along their route. Your provided code does not allow to reproduce your issue as you only showed some handlers. Alternatively subscribe to your shapes directly.

Comment: Can you somehow determine in which cases this event does not occur?
Perhaps this happens when the button is released outside the bounds of `m: Map`?

Comment: @BionicCode I've tried that approach but still doesn't work all the time...

Comment: @EldHasp not it happens inside the bounds of the map.

Comment: Can you check if the PreviewMouseUp event always occurs or not?
Also check the MouseLeave event to make sure the cursor doesn't leave the element.

Comment: @EldHasp The PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp doesn't occur always either; Yes the cursor doesn't leave the element I've tested with MouseLeave.

Comment: For some odd reason the MouseUp events seems to fire only when fast clicking...

Comment: Could it be a bug of the "m: Map" element?
Replace it for the test with some standard WPF panel and test the behavior.
Thus, it will be possible to localize the problem: is it exactly the use of "m: Map" or is it a problem of a more general nature.